# Calculate conditional mean in R with dplyr (like group by in SQL)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with a list of cities and daily temperature recordings

```
data = data.frame(c("Chicago", "Chicago", "New York", "New York", "Denver"),
                  c(25, 36, 23, 24, 42))
```

I want to add a third column that is the average temperature by city

```
avgtemp = c(30.5, 30.5, 23.5, 23.5, 42)
```

I have tried to do this using the package `dplyr`, but have not had success. What is the best way to achieve this, noting that the full dataset contains 50,000 rows, thus I want the code to be efficient.

Comment: What is the meaning of "but have not had success"? Please show attempts, error message and so on.

Comment: Try `ave(data[, 2], data[, 1])` if the values are actually numeric. @CathG fixed to match their desired output.

Comment: If the data are large and performance is an issue, you could try data.table

Comment: If you want to do it with `dplyr`, you could use `group_by` in combination with `mutate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for (if you want to use dplyr) is a combination of the functions `group_by`and `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)
city <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c")
temp <- 1:5
df <- data.frame(city, temp)

df %>% group_by(city) %>% mutate(mean(temp))
```

Which would output:

```
    city  temp mean(temp)
  (fctr) (int)      (dbl)
1      a     1        1.5
2      a     2        1.5
3      b     3        3.5
4      b     4        3.5
5      c     5        5.0
```

On a side note, I do not think 50,000 rows is that big of a data set for dplyr. I would not worry too much unless this code is going to be inside some kind of loop or you have 1M+ rows. As Heroka sugested in the comments, data.table is a better alternative when it comes to performance in most cases.

**Edit:** removed unnecessary step

Comment: This is good, but how do I add the average to data frame?

Comment: The `mutate(mean(temp))` part is the one that creates the additional mean column. 

I am not sure if I understand what you really mean. The original data frame is not affected because there was no assignment. The code example is just printing the result.

`df <- df %>% group_by(city) %>% mutate(mean(temp))`

Comment: if i want to append this column to the original dataframe, how would i do that?

Comment: `df <- df %>% group_by(city) %>% mutate(mean(temp))`